# how to get div inside another div by calling document.getElementbyId

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id = "a" >   </div>
<div id ="b">  child  </div>
```

so i have go two div's here i want to get div"b" inside div"a"
if i type:

```
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("b").value;
```

it will give me this output

```
<div id = "a" > child  </div>
```

but what i want is

```
<div id = "a" >  <div id ="b">  child  </div> </div>
```

Comment: BTW value is not a valid attribute for div. Maybe you meant innerHTML?

Comment: yes exactly buddy you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the time it took me to write this, other answers were made saying the same.

Run the snippet to see the code in action...

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a");
  var b = document.getElementById("b");
  a.appendChild(b)
}, 1000)
```

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.border div{
 width: 80%;
 margin: 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="a" class="border">A</div>
<div id="b" class="border">B</div>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, brilliant!

Answer (score 6):

Try `appendChild()`;

```js
document.getElementById('a').appendChild(document.getElementById('b'));
```

```html
<div id = "a" ></div>
<div id ="b">child</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use element's [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) as follows:

`document.getElementById("a").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("b").outerHTML;`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, and it doesn't apply in this case, but if you do it that way, doesn't it remove any attached event handlers?

Comment: Well it will just change the content of `#a` to outer HTML of `#b`. @KarenGrigoryan or @Christian4423 answers using `appendChild` will preserve them. But I haven't seen any info about events nor moving/appending element in the question so I thought OP wants just the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the tag b to tag a copying it outerHTML

```
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("b").outerHTML;
```

Then if you want to remove the b tag use

```
document.getElementById('b').remove();
```